# Google Sign In iOS cannot sign in

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I have integrated Google Sign in for my iOS app. When I click the sign in button, it asks for permission to open an in app browser, which directs me to a login page. I click on my google account (which says "signed out" to the right). when I put in my password, I continually get "Unable to sign in to your Google Account: Delete cookies" each time. Any reason as to why?

[image]

Comment: Google is having an OAuth outage right now; this might be affecting you. https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-iam/19001#19001002

Answer (score 1):

As Google was experiencing the OAuth Outage, your application should be able to run once it is over. I had the same problem and mine works again:)